# iPhone code signing key doesn't match provisioning profile "xxxxxxx"

Tags: ios, xamarin, certificate, key, provisioning-profile

For about 17 weeks I've been building an iOS app using Xamarin Studio. I've added an iPhone to the developer profile and edited the provisioning profile to include this new iPhone, to test and debugg my app (I was running it on my MacBook (but with OSX Mavericks 10.9), and all worked well.

Last week, my supervisor asked me to upload the app to another iPhone, to show a demo of the app to our customers. I added the device in the developer portal, and linked it to the already existing Provisioning Profile. When trying to run the app, I got the error: "No iPhone code signing key matches specified provisioning profile".

A coworker and I have tried to resolve this issue by importing Certificates and Keys from another MacBook, on which the app still ran, onto this MacBook. After that didn't work out, we tried deleting the Certificates and Private Keys in the Keychain on this MacBook and re-importing them from the other MacBook.

We tried to create a new Provisioning Profile and re-link both iPhones, but the error still occurred.

Now, the app won't even sign on the first iPhone I linked to the first Provisioning Profile in the developer portal, nor will it sign using the emulators in Xamarin Studio

What I wanted to ask was what makes this problem occur, and how to fix it. Do we need to create a new certificate and provisioning profile altogether, or is there something we can do to fix this problem without having to create new certificates and provisioning profiles?

I've contacted Apple Support, they redirect me to Xamarin. Xamarin redirects me to Apple Support... I just can't get help from the officials, so I'll try the community.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a HelloWorld app on the phones using Xcode?

Comment: In Xcode, I get the error: "No matching provisioning profiles found". "fixing" the issue with the button does nothing.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be possible to get help from Apple support. I mean, if you cannot deploy an obj-c/swift app using Xcode, then Xamarin is not to blame

Comment: I tried that. I explained the problem with my certificates and keys, but because I mention I get an error in Xamarin, they say it's their problem. Using up TSIs for this is not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's tedious, but I would start over re-creating certificates and profiles.

You could follow this lovely step-by-step guide: [Publishing to the App Store](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/#Creating_and_Installing_a_Distribution_Profile)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After long debate with my department-manager, we've come to the conclusion that our certificates and profiles were a mess, and we cleaned it all up, and started from scratch, as you said. All is well now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to Xcode, create a new project. Select your company name(do not select user), then type in anything you want as your bundle identifier.

2.Go back to Xamarin studio and change the bundle identifier to match the one you just created in Xcode.

3.Update the provisioning profile in options to include the bundle identifier you created in Xcode. Build, then Debug the solution and it should work.

For me the issue was the team identifier contained the only provisions, and the only selection in Xamarin studio were users. I just created a new project in Xcode that pointed to the team provision, then used that new bundle identifier (that was uploaded to the Apple dev site) in Xamarin studio.

Answer (score 0):

you have assigned wrong developer and with your provisioning profile.
select it right on going into build setting>> code signing and select provisioning profile you create with developer account.

Comment: This is something I've already looked into. I have selected the right provisioning profile in the project settings, but that's not the problem. The problem is probably about the keys I have (and had for all this time).

Comment: i do not understand your problem exactly then, the best solution will be, Remove all related provisioning profiles from xcode , and create your certs again and create new provisioning Profile install.

Comment: The thing is that we've reached the maximum amount of Certificates, and that the certificates are shared across multiple projects. Creating new provisioning profiles alone doesn't work, we've already tried that.